# MATLAB ismembertol compare 2 matrices by any row

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison

Lets say I've two matrices A and x:

```
A=[10,10;
   20,20;
   30,30;
   NaN,NaN
   NaN,NaN];
x=[10,9;
   32,25;
   19,21;
   11,10;
   NaN,NaN];
```

I want to compare both matrices and find rows of x that correspond to any row of A within a certain tolerance of +-0.01 (=+-10%). So in this case:

Row 1 of x matches a row (row 1) in A that is within the tolerance.

Row 2 of x nearly matches a row (row 2) in A, but it is outside of +- 10%.

Row 3 of x matches a row (row 2) in A that is within the tolerance.

Row 4 of x matches a row (row 1 again) in A within the tolerance.

Row 5 of x can be ignored (only NaN).

It is guaranteed that A and x have the same size and number of elements. However, the rows are not in order, so I can't compare row-by-row. I just want to know if a row in x matches ANY row in A and if so, I'd like to save the index of that row. So in my case I'd prefer to have an output (logical) vector like:

```
v=[1,0,1,1,0]; % Logical vector with matching rows of x
id=find(v==1); % Result is [1,3,4], finds the indices
```

I tried various combinations of

```
ismembertol(A,x,0.1) % and ismembertol(A,x,0.1,'ByRows',true)
```

by using 'find', 'any', 'all' but I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: The problem is the `NaN` values. If a row contains `NaN`, it won't match any other value, even another `NaN`. It seems you want to disregard those `NaN`' values. But then if the row is only `NaN` you say it shouldn't match any other row. You need to clarify these criteria. Also, are the "unwanted" `NaN` values always in the last column, and so that column can just be ignored?

Comment: I can 'reduce' the problem by ignoring the 3rd column, I'll edit my post.
The whole lines of NaN can still happen and will always be the last lines. Let's say both matrices can have a maximum of 10 rows, then it can e.g. happen that A has 6 NaN-rows (5-10) and x may have another amount of NaN-rows (higher, lower or equal to A).

Comment: So, if the last column is ignored, can it be assumed that any remaining `NaN` should cause the row to not match any other row?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't clarify that before. 
Also the rows of both A and x will always be of type 'number,number' or 'NaN,NaN'. A case like 'number,NaN' or vice-versa can't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) with the `'ByRows'` option:

```
result = ismembertol(x, A, 0.1, 'ByRows', true);
```

Note that:

- `NaN` values cause a row to not match any other row.
- As per the documentation, `tol` is interpreted as a fraction of `tol*max(abs([A(:); x(:)]))`.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. I tried that before as well but now I see my mistake. I always did A,x but now I see that x,A makes more sense. So it was all about my input order for the ismembertol function. Thank you!

Comment: @user10790707 Yes, after I posted my answer I saw you almost had it :-)